# "Кажется слышно", где "кажется" не вводное, - я ошибаюсь?

Tags: вводные-слова, невыделение-вводных

> Самое красивое в Бразилии – это облака. Они так близко, что кажется
>   слышно, как они рвутся в небе.

Формально - "кажется слышным", а нельзя.

Как же ж жить?

Comment: А почему бы не "как будто слышно"?

Comment: Не-а, не выход.

Comment: Почему?********

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уж и боюсь что-то предлагать (чтоб не навредить автору).
В большинстве случаев (в похожих предложениях) "кажется" обособляется:

*Тишина такая, что, кажется, слышно, как уходящее солнце задевает иголки сосен…*
*От шокового состояния, кажется, слышно, как в воздухе рвутся незримые нити.*

Но нашелся вот такой интересный текст:
*Кажется, слышно, как колотится сердце в груди, как лесная мышь перебегает дорогу или скачет потревоженная белка. Но в лесу тихо. Когда выходят на опушку, в полях **кажется светло.***
[**П. Н. Краснов. От Двуглавого Орла к красному знамени**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=VcxoCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA524&lpg=PA524&dq=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA&source=bl&ots=ETvHaqgfh0&sig=t5kjhD613KOIIRkpDSWXrGdXiho&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-weqr4pHYAhVEElAKHQbBACgQ6AEIOzAE#v=onepage&q=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA&f=false)

Думаю, что можно не ставить запятые (кажется слышно = почти слышно).

Comment: Понимаете, Римма, может быть такое же предложение со вводным "кажется", как у Галины. Но, если я правильно понял Галину, она хочет сказать, употребив "кажется" **НЕ** как вводное слово, а как член предложения. Просто есть два варианта выражения мысли. Вот только мне кажется, что именно со словом К. так не скажешь. Самое интересное, что я на днях (вроде вчера) сам пытался сформулировать то же самое, только со словом "оказалось", и понимал, что по смыслу там творительный падеж, а правильно сказать можно только с наречием, но всё равно по смыслу выходит криво. В итоге сформулировал по-другому.

Comment: Римма! Приму! Автор пусть думает, но Вы с Артёмрм меня убедили. )))  Почему не ставите оценки за мои суперумнейшие вопросы? Я ставлю всегда, когда берусь отвечать. А вот за ответы - это "по совести",

Comment: Я за некоторые поставил Вам, а в этом — точно, забыл.)) Исправился, он стоит того! Видимо, не поставил сначала, п. ч. расстроился, что Вы мою ситуацию "угнали".))

Answer (score 2):

Самое красивое в Бразилии – это облака. Они так близко, что кажется слышно, как они рвутся в небе.

**А мне это предложение не нравится.**

Во первых, на слух "кажется слышно" воспринимается как "неправильное" сказуемое, так как в устной речи  вводное слово в такой позиции не выделяется паузами.

Во-вторых, непонятен сам образ - "облака, которые рвутся". Мне кажется, что они  тихо-неслышно распадаются на части. Или они взрываются, как снаряды? Какие-то странные слуховые галлюцинации там, где скорее могут возникнуть красивые зрительные образы. В общем, читатель в недоумении.

Comment: @ Jasmin,согласен с вами.

Answer (score 1):

Слово "кажется" в качестве члена предложения имеет следующие значения: 1. Иметь какой-л. вид, производить впечатление. // чем. Вызывать, внушать мысли о чём-л.. безл. кому. Представляться воображению, мысли. Мне кажется, что мы уже где-то встречались. // безл. Чудиться, мерещиться.

В качестве вводного: как будто, по-видимому. Как видно, ни одно из значений не подходит в этом примере.

А вот в качестве вводного - вполне.
Самое красивое в Бразилии – это облака. Они так близко, что, кажется **(вероятно, наверняка)**, слышно, как они рвутся в небе.

Comment: Что-то не могу понять конец ответа: ни одно из значений вводного не подходит, а в качестве вводного вполне...

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, я имел в виду значение как полнозначного члена не подходит. Исправил.

Comment: @Серж  Поправьте ответ ещё раз. Описочка вышла.

Comment: А почему в качестве вводного вы его не выделили в конце?

Comment: Механически скопировал, не заметил.